# Farsi alphabet order for glossary

Tags: indexing, glossaries, sorting

I am using `glossaries` with `makeidx` in a Farsi document with `xepersian`. Currently it sorts the output using Arabic alphabet order and places words starting with گ, چ, پ and ژ at the end of list. How can I force Farsi alphabet order?

Comment: Could you, please, post MWE of your glossary? I'm trying to typeset a glossary sorted using Arabic alphabet but it fails till now. You can see my question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86181/a-tool-for-creating-a-dictionary-with-right-to-left-script. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For indexing non-European languages you need to use `xindy`, not `makeidx`. There is `xindy` support for Persian available on CTAN: [`xindy-persian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xindy-persian).