# Creating left to right and right to left dictionaries using Glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, polyglossia, right-to-left

I want to produce two bilingual dictionaries Arabic-English and English-Arabic. I've found [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86181/a-tool-for-creating-a-dictionary-with-right-to-left-script) which seems of some interest for my needs... So I build this file, based on it

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newcommand*{\glossaryname}{Dictionary}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,nopostdot,xindy]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\dictentry}[3][\dictlabel]{%
 \def\dictlabel{#2}%
 \newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#3,description={#2}}%
 \glsadd{#1}%
}

\makeglossaries

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[locale=mashriq]{arabic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Traditional Arabic}


\newglossarystyle{RLsuper}{%
 \glossarystyle{super}% base this style on 'super'
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
     \begin{supertabular}{lr}}% adjust column specifiers
    {\end{supertabular}}%
  % switch name and description columns:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##3} & ##2\\}%
}


\begin{document}
%%% ENTRIES %%%%%%%%%%%
\dictentry{on}{\textarabic{هو}}%
\dictentry{ja}{\textarabic{انا}}%
\dictentry{pies}{\textarabic{كلب}}%
\dictentry{Dice}{\textarabic{زهرة نرد}}%
\dictentry{Commutative laws}{\textarabic{قوانين إبدالية}}%
\dictentry{Maximum likelihood estimate}{\textarabic{مقدر الاحتمال الأعظم}}%

\RTLdblcol
\printglossary[style=RLsuper]%

\end{document}
```

which gave on the first compilation a good pdf file (what I can't add to discussion because I don't know how!)...

But when I copy this file and create another file which is strictly the same, for a second try, the compilation gave me a blank pdf file... An empty file... So my questions are:

1. What happens between the two compilations?
2. I want to create two dictionaries, one sorted in Arabic order, and the same    dictionary but sorted in the English alphabet order, how can I do this?
3. For long entries like "Maximum likelihood estimate", can I split the glossary output in two lines (produced by macros like this, based on something like `\begin{tabular} m{2.5cm}m{2.5cm}} \end{tabular}` for example...
4. A question which seems simple, but of interest for me... How can I insert things like rules for example between the entries... exactly `\hrule\hrule`...

I can't try it because it doesn't compile! More generally, where are stocked the entries after sorting? How can I do small changes on it directly?

Comment: Try moving your definitions into the preamble. The first LaTeX run will produce an empty document since the document only contains the glossary which doesn't exist yet. You then need to run `makeglossaries` which should create the associated file that will be inserted into the document on the next LaTeX run.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "preamble"... If it's what is before \begin{document}, it's the case...

Comment: Other thing... I think that running makeglossaries is automatic... If it's not the case, what are the good commands?

Comment: I meant your entry definitions. Your `\dictentry` commands are in the document environment and since they use `\newglossaryentry`, this means you're defining entries in the document environment not in the preamble. Use `\GlsSetXdyLanguage` (described in [Language and Encodings](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:langenc) in the user manual) to set a different language for each glossary. You can check if `makeglossaries` ran correctly by looking for the log file `.glg`.

Comment: The glossaries package comes with a sample file that has English and French dictionaries (The source is [sample-lang.tex](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/sample-langdict.tex) and the corresponding PDF is [sample-langdict.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/sample-langdict.pdf).) You may be able to adapt that code for your example.

Comment: Thanks for your help, which seems very helpful. I'll read this doc after solving some epinous problem happens to me...posed in the site.. With your permission, I'll ask your help  for it...  I'll be soon in the end of my book !

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196003/problem-with-the-font-traditional-arabic-for-aligning-parenthesis?noredirect=1#comment454173_196003

Comment: @NicolaTalbot would you see please the discussion I've opened here
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250609/dictionnary-english-french-arabic-with-glossaries-package
Many thanks